# How can I round a value to a multiple of an integer in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, rounding, floor

How can I make a specific cell (B2) from all sheets to automatically round down the input number to the nearest multiple of 4 integers?

Example. When I input a number in cell B2 (33.33), it need to be rounded down to the nearest multiple of 4 integers (32).

If possible, I want that code works for all sheets. What script codes should I use?

Comment: What I'm asking is a SCRIPT CODE.  Something like this: function onEdit() {
    if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue() == "Name") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setFontColor("Green");
  }

Comment: what code should I use to rounddown a number in a specific cell, the above color-changing script code apply to the whole spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

### 2021 update:

[Google Docs provides `CEILING`, `FLOOR`, and `MROUND`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093487), which will each round to the nearest multiple of the 2nd argument

| Formula | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `=CEILING(33.33, 4)` | 36 |
| `=FLOOR(33.33, 4)` (wanted by question) | 32 |
| `=MROUND(126.85, 0.04)` | 126.84 |

### Original Answer

Divide the initial value by 4, round that down, and then multiply it by 4 again

As a "normal" formula:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(B2/4)*4
```

As a custom function

```
function Floor4() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var initial = spreadsheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2').setValue(Math.floor(initial/4)*4);
};
```